# Проблемы с pom.xml

Tags: java, maven, library

Не понимаю, в чем проблема. Даже не могу четко сформулировать вопрос так, как недавно работаю с maven.

pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>net.hnm.rp</groupId>
    <artifactId>roleplay</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <name>RolePlay</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>
    <!-- DEPENDENCIES -->
    <dependencies>
        <!-- BukkitAPI -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.bukkit</groupId>
            <artifactId>bukkit</artifactId>
            <version>1.12.2-R0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- HikariCP -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.zaxxer</groupId>
            <artifactId>HikariCP-java6</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.1</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Javassist Library -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.javassist</groupId>
            <artifactId>javassist</artifactId>
            <version>3.18.1-GA</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- SLF4J Library -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Lombok -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <version>1.14.8</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sk89q.worldguard</groupId>
            <artifactId>worldguard-bukkit</artifactId>
            <version>7.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.milkbowl.vault</groupId>
            <artifactId>VaultAPI</artifactId>
            <version>1.14.8</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.shampaggon.crackshot</groupId>
            <artifactId>sample</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
            <scope>system</scope>
            <systemPath>${project.basedir}/libs/CrackShot.jar</systemPath>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>nl.pim16aap2.bigDoors</groupId>
            <artifactId>sample</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
            <scope>system</scope>
            <systemPath>${project.basedir}/libs/BigDoors.jar</systemPath>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>spigot-repo</id>
            <url>https://hub.spigotmc.org/nexus/content/repositories/snapshots</url>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>sk89q-repo</id>
            <url>https://maven.sk89q.com/repo/</url>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>vault-repo</id>
            <url>http://nexus.hc.to/content/repositories/pub_releases</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
    <build>
        <defaultGoal>clean install</defaultGoal>
        <finalName>RolePlay</finalName>
        <sourceDirectory>${basedir}/src</sourceDirectory>
        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>src</directory>
                <filtering>true</filtering>
                <includes>
                    <include>*.*</include>
                    <include>plugin.yml</include>
                    <include>${basedir}/libs</include>
                </includes>
            </resource>
        </resources>
        <plugins>
            <!-- Shade the necessary libs -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>shade</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <!--<minimizeJar>true</minimizeJar>-->
                            <createDependencyReducedPom>false</createDependencyReducedPom>
                            <artifactSet>
                                <includes>
                                    <include>org.slf4j:*</include>
                                    <include>com.zaxxer:*</include>
                                    <include>org.javassist:javassist</include>
                                </includes>
                            </artifactSet>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <!-- Compile -->
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                    <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Предупреждения в консоли:

```
Downloading: http://nexus.hc.to/content/repositories/pub_releases/org/bukkit/bukkit/1.12.2-R0.1-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml
[WARNING] Could not transfer metadata org.bukkit:bukkit:1.12.2-R0.1-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml from/to vault-repo (http://nexus.hc.to/content/repositories/pub_releases): Connect to nexus.hc.to:80 [nexus.hc.to/167.99.232.82] failed: Operation timed out (Connection timed out)
[WARNING] Failure to transfer org.bukkit:bukkit:1.12.2-R0.1-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml from http://nexus.hc.to/content/repositories/pub_releases was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of vault-repo has elapsed or updates are forced. Original error: Could not transfer metadata org.bukkit:bukkit:1.12.2-R0.1-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml from/to vault-repo (http://nexus.hc.to/content/repositories/pub_releases): Connect to nexus.hc.to:80 [nexus.hc.to/167.99.232.82] failed: Operation timed out (Connection timed out)
Downloading: http://nexus.hc.to/content/repositories/pub_releases/com/sk89q/worldguard/worldguard-bukkit/maven-metadata.xml
[WARNING] Could not transfer metadata com.sk89q.worldguard:worldguard-bukkit/maven-metadata.xml from/to vault-repo (http://nexus.hc.to/content/repositories/pub_releases): Connect to nexus.hc.to:80 [nexus.hc.to/167.99.232.82] failed: Operation timed out (Connection timed out)
[WARNING] Failure to transfer com.sk89q.worldguard:worldguard-bukkit/maven-metadata.xml from http://nexus.hc.to/content/repositories/pub_releases was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of vault-repo has elapsed or updates are forced. Original error: Could not transfer metadata com.sk89q.worldguard:worldguard-bukkit/maven-metadata.xml from/to vault-repo (http://nexus.hc.to/content/repositories/pub_releases): Connect to nexus.hc.to:80 [nexus.hc.to/167.99.232.82] failed: Operation timed out (Connection timed out)
Downloading: http://nexus.hc.to/content/repositories/pub_releases/org/bukkit/bukkit/1.14.4-R0.1-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml
[WARNING] Could not transfer metadata org.bukkit:bukkit:1.14.4-R0.1-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml from/to vault-repo (http://nexus.hc.to/content/repositories/pub_releases): Connect to nexus.hc.to:80 [nexus.hc.to/167.99.232.82] failed: Operation timed out (Connection timed out)
[WARNING] Failure to transfer org.bukkit:bukkit:1.14.4-R0.1-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml from http://nexus.hc.to/content/repositories/pub_releases was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of vault-repo has elapsed or updates are forced. Original error: Could not transfer metadata org.bukkit:bukkit:1.14.4-R0.1-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml from/to vault-repo (http://nexus.hc.to/content/repositories/pub_releases): Connect to nexus.hc.to:80 [nexus.hc.to/167.99.232.82] failed: Operation timed out (Connection timed out)
Downloading: http://nexus.hc.to/content/repositories/pub_releases/com/sk89q/worldedit/worldedit-bukkit/7.0.1-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml
[WARNING] Could not transfer metadata com.sk89q.worldedit:worldedit-bukkit:7.0.1-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml from/to vault-repo (http://nexus.hc.to/content/repositories/pub_releases): Connect to nexus.hc.to:80 [nexus.hc.to/167.99.232.82] failed: Operation timed out (Connection timed out)
[WARNING] Failure to transfer com.sk89q.worldedit:worldedit-bukkit:7.0.1-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml from http://nexus.hc.to/content/repositories/pub_releases was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of vault-repo has elapsed or updates are forced. Original error: Could not transfer metadata com.sk89q.worldedit:worldedit-bukkit:7.0.1-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml from/to vault-repo (http://nexus.hc.to/content/repositories/pub_releases): Connect to nexus.hc.to:80 [nexus.hc.to/167.99.232.82] failed: Operation timed out (Connection timed out)
Downloading: http://nexus.hc.to/content/repositories/pub_releases/com/sk89q/worldguard/worldguard-core/7.0.1-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml
[WARNING] Could not transfer metadata com.sk89q.worldguard:worldguard-core:7.0.1-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml from/to vault-repo (http://nexus.hc.to/content/repositories/pub_releases): Connect to nexus.hc.to:80 [nexus.hc.to/167.99.232.82] failed: Operation timed out (Connection timed out)
[WARNING] Failure to transfer com.sk89q.worldguard:worldguard-core:7.0.1-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml from http://nexus.hc.to/content/repositories/pub_releases was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of vault-repo has elapsed or updates are forced. Original error: Could not transfer metadata com.sk89q.worldguard:worldguard-core:7.0.1-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml from/to vault-repo (http://nexus.hc.to/content/repositories/pub_releases): Connect to nexus.hc.to:80 [nexus.hc.to/167.99.232.82] failed: Operation timed out (Connection timed out)
Downloading: http://nexus.hc.to/content/repositories/pub_releases/com/sk89q/worldguard/worldguard-libs/core/7.0.1-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml
[WARNING] Could not transfer metadata com.sk89q.worldguard.worldguard-libs:core:7.0.1-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml from/to vault-repo (http://nexus.hc.to/content/repositories/pub_releases): Connect to nexus.hc.to:80 [nexus.hc.to/167.99.232.82] failed: Operation timed out (Connection timed out)
[WARNING] Failure to transfer com.sk89q.worldguard.worldguard-libs:core:7.0.1-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml from http://nexus.hc.to/content/repositories/pub_releases was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of vault-repo has elapsed or updates are forced. Original error: Could not transfer metadata com.sk89q.worldguard.worldguard-libs:core:7.0.1-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml from/to vault-repo (http://nexus.hc.to/content/repositories/pub_releases): Connect to nexus.hc.to:80 [nexus.hc.to/167.99.232.82] failed: Operation timed out (Connection timed out)
Downloading: http://nexus.hc.to/content/repositories/pub_releases/com/sk89q/worldedit/worldedit-core/7.0.1-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml
[WARNING] Could not transfer metadata com.sk89q.worldedit:worldedit-core:7.0.1-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml from/to vault-repo (http://nexus.hc.to/content/repositories/pub_releases): Connect to nexus.hc.to:80 [nexus.hc.to/167.99.232.82] failed: Operation timed out (Connection timed out)
[WARNING] Failure to transfer com.sk89q.worldedit:worldedit-core:7.0.1-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml from http://nexus.hc.to/content/repositories/pub_releases was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of vault-repo has elapsed or updates are forced. Original error: Could not transfer metadata com.sk89q.worldedit:worldedit-core:7.0.1-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml from/to vault-repo (http://nexus.hc.to/content/repositories/pub_releases): Connect to nexus.hc.to:80 [nexus.hc.to/167.99.232.82] failed: Operation timed out (Connection timed out)
Downloading: http://nexus.hc.to/content/repositories/pub_releases/com/sk89q/worldedit/worldedit-libs/core/7.0.1-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml
[WARNING] Could not transfer metadata com.sk89q.worldedit.worldedit-libs:core:7.0.1-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml from/to vault-repo (http://nexus.hc.to/content/repositories/pub_releases): Connect to nexus.hc.to:80 [nexus.hc.to/167.99.232.82] failed: Operation timed out (Connection timed out)
[WARNING] Failure to transfer com.sk89q.worldedit.worldedit-libs:core:7.0.1-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml from http://nexus.hc.to/content/repositories/pub_releases was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of vault-repo has elapsed or updates are forced. Original error: Could not transfer metadata com.sk89q.worldedit.worldedit-libs:core:7.0.1-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml from/to vault-repo (http://nexus.hc.to/content/repositories/pub_releases): Connect to nexus.hc.to:80 [nexus.hc.to/167.99.232.82] failed: Operation timed out (Connection timed out)
Downloading: http://nexus.hc.to/content/repositories/pub_releases/net/milkbowl/vault/VaultAPI/1.14.8/VaultAPI-1.14.8.pom
```

Comment: Проблема в том, что ваш компьютер по какой-то причине не может подключиться к серверу nexus.hc.to. Может дело в компьютере, может дело в сервере, может дело в одном из десятка разделяющих вас сетевых устройств. Точно, что проблема не в Maven и не в Java.

Comment: просто http://nexus.hc.to/content/repositories/pub_releases не доступен